# Show that for an odd integer $n ≥ 5$, $5^{n-1}\binom{n}{0}-5^{n-2}\binom{n}{1}+…+\binom{n}{n-1}$ is not a prime number.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, polynomials, prime-factorization

I would prefer no total solutions and just a hint as to whether or not I’m at a dead end with my solution method.

So far this is my work:

From the binomial expansion,

$$\sum_{j=0}^n 5^{n-j}(-1)^j\binom{n}{j}= (5+(-1))^n = 4^n$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}5^{n-1-j}(-1)^j\binom{n}{j} = \frac{4^n+1}{5}$$
However, $\frac{4^n+1}{5} = \frac{(4+1)}{5}(4^{n-1}-4^{n-2}+…+1)= 4^{n-1}-4^{n-2}+…+1$.

Here I am stuck. My attempts have been to find a factorization of the polynomial $\sum_{j=0}^k (-x)^j $ where $k$ is even. However, I’m reasonably certain there’s an argument to be made that the polynomial is irreducible modulo $2$ implying that it’s irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$.

This leads me to thinking that this route is a dead end since I can’t find any specific primes which reduce the expression nicely under a mod.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Is the desired expression the one in the header, the one which ends with the $\binom n{n-1}$ term, or the one in the body, that ends with the $\binom nn$ term?  If the former, why is the sign negative?

Comment: We want to show the expression in the header isn’t prime. Sorry the - is a typo. @lulu

Comment: So...why do you consider a different sum in the body?

Comment: I suggest:  edit your post to include the first  several values of the relevant sequence. (for, say, $n=5,7,9,11,13$).  That might clarify what is intended and, of course, simple patterns might emergre

Comment: @lulu It isn’t a different sum, I’m rewriting the sum in the header to a simpler form in hopes that it yields intuition.

Comment: @lulu The first sum in the body is used to calculate the sum in the header. The former contains $j = 0$ because we're stating the binomial identity. The latter accounts for that, hence the +1 in $4^n + 1$.

Comment: I would start with "If $n$ is a multiple of $5$, then.... and in the case $n > 5$ is not a multiple of $5$..."

Comment: Hint: The Sophie Germain identity states that $a^4 + 4b^4 = [ (a+b)^2 + b^2] [(a-b)^2 + b^2]$. Apply the fact that $n$ is an odd integer.

Comment: @CalvinLin Apologies if it’s rude to reply on the behalf of Brian Moehring, however, I think the reason he thought that multiples of $5$ were valuable to look at is the fact that there will be some multiple of $5$ terms in $4^{n-1}-4^{n-2}+…+1$ which all reduce to 1 mod 5, so it follows that the sum will be 0 mod 5.

Comment: @TG173 Even more directly, since $\binom{n}{n-1}=n$, when $n$ is a multiple of $5$, each term in the original sum has a factor of $5$.  When you use this with the form $(4^n+1)/5$, the only question is whether we can have $4^n+1 = 25$.  Then after that, we know $5$ isn't a factor, so we can consider $4^n+1$ by itself and look for prime factors strictly greater than $5$.  True, I had no plan in mind, but that is what I'd look at -- Sophie Germain is definitely faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show that for odd integer $n$, $ \frac{ 4^n + 1 } { 5}$ is composite.

You're on the right track, though this numerator isn't irreducible, so **hint:** Find the factorization.

Writing $n = 2k+1$, does $ 4 \times 4^{2k} + 1$ remind you of any factorizations?

> **Hint:** Sophie Germain's identity is $a^4 + 4b^4 = [ (a+b)^2 + b^2] [(a-b)^2 + b^2]$

> For odd integer $n$, this allows us to factorize the numerator $4^n + 1$ into 2 terms, both greater than 5 (and one of which is a multiple of 5). Hence, the expression is composite.

Comment: $\dfrac{ 4^8 + 1 } { 5}$ is not an integer, friend Calvin.

Comment: It is just a lapsus. Edit changing $+$ by $-$. Regards.

Comment: @Piquito Hm, even then $(4^8 - 1 )/5$ isn't prime, so I'm not quite sure how I got that (I guess I typed too fast in Wolfram Alpha). Removed that reference.

Comment: Do what you want.